# Could not import 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt, django-authentication

Full Error:
Could not import 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

And this is the pip freeze in the virtual env:

```
(backend) PS D:\js\backend> pip freeze                          
asgiref==3.5.1
Django==4.0.4
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.1.0
mysqlclient==2.1.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2022.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2022.1
```

in the middle of the error, it addresses some lines across views.py for decorators:

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, JsonResponse
from .models import Tweet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework import status
```

I'm not sure if they're even related

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'` this is provided by **djangorestframework-jwt** wich is not not being maintained anymore  .  Just uninstall it
instead  use  `'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'`
that comes from **djangorestframework-simplejwt**

**1 -** install **djangorestframework-simplejwt** : `pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`

**2-** Your `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'` should be like this  :

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 
),
```

**3 -**  in your root `urls.py` file (or any other url config), include routes for Simple JWT’s `TokenObtainPairView` and `TokenRefreshView` views:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ...
]
```

for more information check the [official documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#)

Comment: In case anyone else is doing this. its not just as simple as replacing the authentication class. you will have to update your urls for logging in/out/etc as well as any front end pieces that touch those new urls (unless you keep the paths the same)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the deprecated parts to use wide spread features in `rest_framework_jwt` which is not implemented in `djangorestframework-simplejwt` library.

Specify the authenticator classes to your own path in the `settings.py` just like this:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'YOUR_AUTH_APP.classes.CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

and create a `classes.py` in `YOUR_AUTH_APP` to fix the imports:

```py
import django
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from django.utils.translation import gettext

django.utils.encoding.smart_text = smart_str # fix deprecated import
django.utils.translation.ugettext = gettext # fix deprecated import
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication  # noqa


class CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        tuple_response = super(CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)
        return tuple_response

    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        user = super(CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication, self).authenticate_credentials(payload)
        return user
```